# what a Difference between col-md-4 and col-md-6

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

what a Difference between col-md-4 and col-md-6 ?

I do not understand this. what is col-md-* ?

Please guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `col-md-*` :

- `col` for **column**
- `md`  for **medium** devices (medium devices : desktops, 992px and up)

4 or 6 values refers to the number of grid columns used.

Since there are total of **12** grid-columns in row.

- `col-md-4` results in **3** Columns of equal size (12/4 =3).
- `col-md-6` results in **2** Columns of equal size (12/6 =2).